# Interpretation of strings from PHP's serialization

Tags: php, serialization

Thanks to Stack Overflow, I just knew what serialize() and unserialize() does in PHP.

I came across this code example in [PHP.net Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php):

```
class obj implements Serializable {
 private $data;
 public function __construct() {
    $this->data = "My private data";
  }
 public function serialize() {
    return serialize($this->data);
 }
 public function unserialize($data) {
    $this->data = unserialize($data);
 }
 public function getData() {
    return $this->data;
 }
}

$obj = new obj;
$ser = serialize($obj);

var_dump($ser);

$newobj = unserialize($ser);

var_dump($newobj->getData());
```

The code produces the below result:

```
string(38) "C:3:"obj":23:{s:15:"My private data";}"
string(15) "My private data"
```

I want to know what "C" means in this string and why it equals to "3" and "obj" and why it equals to "23."

I know "s" means string and it contains 15 characters, but I can't understand C and obj and their results.

Answer (score 4):

PHP's serialisation format is based a lot on declaring what something is and then declaring how many of the following characters belong to it. So `C` means a **c**lass, `3` means that the following three characters will tell you what class it is, `obj` is those three characters telling you the class name, `23` tells you that the following 23 characters describe the object's data, and the rest is self explanatory.

Comment: Specifically, `C` means it is a class that implements the `Serializable` interface.  Other classes will be serialized with `O` instead.

Answer (score 1):

C = class

3 - "obj" has 3 characters

23 - because {s:15:"My private data";} has 23 characters